# Jest: check how many times a mocked module function was called

Tags: jestjs

I am using the module waait in my code to allow me to do things like:

```
import * as wait from 'waait';
await wait(500);
```

I have created a manual mock:

```
module.exports = (() => {
  return Promise.resolve();
});
```

I then want to have assertions like this in my test:

```
import * as wait from 'waait';
expect(wait).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(wait).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(1000);
```

When I run that, I get:

```
expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalledTimes()

jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
Received: undefined
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The manual mock you have created is not a [mock](http://xunitpatterns.com/Mock%20Object.html) at all but a [fake](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fake%20Object.html) (i.e. an alternative implementation).

You don't even need it. You can remove the manual mock and write your test like this:

```
import * as wait from 'waait';

jest.mock('waait');
wait.mockResolvedValue(undefined);

it('does something', () => {
    // run the tested code here
    // ...

    // check the results against the expectations
    expect(wait).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(wait).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(1000);
});
```